# Display multiple dataset on same google chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, linechart

I'm trying to make burndown chart with google chart.

I already have set up all my needed data and splitted to 2 different datasets, one for the guideline, the other for the remaining points.

I'm now having the problem, that i'm not able to display both line at the same time. it display either the guidline or the remaining points.
I joined the dataset but still no success:

```
  var joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(guidelineData, remainingData, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('burndown-chart'));

  chart.draw(joinedData, options);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lvx5tdy6/6/

Has anyone some idea how i can solve it?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have only two data points for the guideline and you're mapping that to the existing set of data, with only the first date a match.
That means you only get one point on the graph.

I see you have irregular time intervals between the data, so you can't use a linear function to map the guideline from `1.0 * guidelineValStart` down to `0.0 * guidelineValStart`.

What you could do is use the actual data and coerce the ideal line to match:

```
var guidelineDateStart = guideline[0].date;
var guidelineValStart = guideline[0].guideline;

var milliS =  1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var numDays = (remaining[remaining.length - 1].date - remaining[0].date) / milliS; // work out the number of days that will be displayed

var remainingValues = remaining.map(function(item, idx) {
  return [
    new Date(item.date), 
    item.remaining, 
    (1.0 - (item.date - guidelineDateStart) / milliS / numDays) * guidelineValStart // adjust the ideal line to suit
  ];
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ab3e31of/4/